# Adding multiple plots to Kivy MeshLinePlot

Tags: python, kivy

I would like to add multiple plots to a graph. The following example only adds the data calculated in the last line of the loop. How can I achieve my aim?

Notes: I can do this fine when using kivy examples which do not use a .kv file and the graph widget is added after running multiple 'graph.add_plot' commands within the loop. I also get that when using the .kv file the widgets are automatically updated and when running from the python code they are not.

```
from kivy.garden.graph import MeshLinePlot
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout
from kivy.lang import Builder
from math import sin

class RootWidget(BoxLayout):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(RootWidget, self).__init__()
        self.plot = MeshLinePlot(color=[.5, .5, 1, 1])

    def start(self):
        #self.ids.graph.add_plot(self.plot) #same result if this line is added here
        for i in range(24):
            data_to_graph = [(x, sin(x)+ i) for x in range(0, 101)] #apply a DC offset to each trace to display multiple traces
            print(data_to_graph)
            self.plot.points =  data_to_graph
            self.ids.graph.add_plot(self.plot)

class GraphDemo(App):
    def build(self):
        return Builder.load_file("mainWindow_play.kv")

if __name__ == "__main__":
    GraphDemo().run()
```

mainWindow_play.kv

```
#:import MeshLinePlot kivy.garden.graph.MeshLinePlot
RootWidget:
    BoxLayout:
        orientation: "vertical"
        BoxLayout:
            size_hint: [1, .8]
            Graph:
                id: graph
                xlabel: "X"
                ylabel: "Y"
                y_ticks_major: 4
                x_ticks_major: 4
                y_grid_label: True
                x_grid_label: True
                padding: 5
                x_grid: True
                y_grid: True
                ymin: -1
                ymax: 25
                xmin: 0
                xmax: 25

        BoxLayout:
            size_hint: [1, .2]
            orientation: "horizontal"
            Button:
                text: "START"
                bold: True
                on_press: root.start()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are only creating one plot, and just changing the plot points for that plot. So the final plot is the last one. A plot can only be added to a graph once, so all but your first `add_plot()` is ignored. And when the plot points are changed, that one plot is updated to show the last points. If you want to see all the plots, you need to create a separate plot for each set of data points. Perhaps like this:

```
class RootWidget(BoxLayout):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(RootWidget, self).__init__()

    def start(self):
        #self.ids.graph.add_plot(self.plot) #same result if this line is added here
        for i in range(24):
            data_to_graph = [(x, sin(x)+ i) for x in range(0, 101)] #apply a DC offset to each trace to display multiple traces
            print(data_to_graph)
            self.plot = MeshLinePlot(color=[.5, .5, 1, 1])
            self.plot.points =  data_to_graph
            self.ids.graph.add_plot(self.plot)
```

Move the creation of the `MeshLinePlot` to inside the loop, so that you are creating a new plot each time and adding it to the graph.